# Angular routes children do not hit

Tags: angular, routes, children

I am using the latest version of Angular. I am trying to define routes with children to follow adequate hierarchy.

I have `app-routing.module.ts` which has the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeRoutes } from './modules/home/home-routing.module';
import { QuickReferenceRoutes } from './modules/quick-references/quick-reference-routing.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  ...QuickReferenceRoutes,
  ...HomeRoutes
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The other files it calles for route are as following:

`home-routing.module`

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

export const HomeRoutes: Route[] = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

`quick-reference-routing.module`

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { QuickRefComponent } from './quick-reference.component';
import { CombatQRFComponent } from './combat-quick-reference/combat-qrf.component';

export const QuickReferenceRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'quick-reference',
        component: QuickRefComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'test', component: CombatQRFComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'quick-reference/combat',
        component: CombatQRFComponent
    }
];
```

So after this setup `quick-reference/combat` loads `CombatQRFComponent`, but at `quick-reference/test` `CombatQRFComponent` does not load it. It loads `QuickRefComponent` instead. I tried to look for this problem, but I can't seem to find anyone with similar problem.

All tutorials say that if you config your routes like this, with children routes, the route `quick-reference/test` should load `CombatQRFComponent`. Instead it loads the component of the parent route.

Edit: Here is a link to the repo for better view of the whole structure: https://github.com/Panglot/DnD_app

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: There is no error at all. It just loads QuickRefComponent instead of CombatQRFComponent. No problems, no errors.

Comment: can you try adding '/test' to you child component path?

Comment: If I add slash I get this error: "Invalid configuration of route 'quick-reference//test': path cannot start with a slash"

Comment: Here's a link to the repo for better view of the whole structure: https://github.com/Panglot/DnD_app

Comment: can you try removing component: QuickRefComponent in quick-reference-routing.module

Comment: Ah yes now they load properly. But how about the case when I want to have a page for quick-reference as well as page for quick-reference/test?

Comment: add a new path object as { path: '', component: QuickRefComponent}

Comment: Ah yes. How dumb of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

    import { QuickRefComponent } from './quick-reference.component';
    import { CombatQRFComponent } from './combat-quick-reference/combat-qrf.component';

    export const QuickReferenceRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'quick-reference',
            children: [
                { path: '', component: QuickRefComponent}
                { path: 'test', component: CombatQRFComponent }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'quick-reference/combat',
            component: CombatQRFComponent
        }
    ];
```